# Left factoring of part of JavaScript grammar

Tags: javascript, parsing, recursion, compiler-construction, grammar

I use a grammar for EcmaScript 5.1 expression:

```
PrimaryExpression :
    this
    Identifier
    Literal
    ArrayLiteral
    ObjectLiteral
    ( Expression )

FunctionExpression :
    function Identifieropt ( FormalParameterListopt ) { FunctionBody }

MemberExpression :
    PrimaryExpression
    FunctionExpression
    MemberExpression [ Expression ]
    MemberExpression . IdentifierName
    new MemberExpression Arguments

NewExpression :
    MemberExpression
    new NewExpression

CallExpression :
    MemberExpression Arguments
    CallExpression Arguments
    CallExpression [ Expression ]
    CallExpression . IdentifierName
Arguments :
    ( )
    ( ArgumentList )

LeftHandSideExpression :
    NewExpression
    CallExpression
```

I rewrite it in Wirth notation to write recursive parser for it.
And what I got:

```
PrimaryExpression = this | Identifier | Literal | ObjectLiteral | "(" ExpressionNoIn ")"

Literal = NullLiteral | BooleanLiteral | NumericLiteral | StringLiteral 

ObjectLiteral = "{" [PropertyNamesAndValues] "}"

MemberExpression = ( PrimaryExpression | FunctionExpression | new MemberExpression Arguments ) MemberExpression'    

MemberExpression' = ( "." Identifier | "[" Expression "]" ) MemberExpression' | e.

NewExpression = ( PrimaryExpression | FunctionExpression ) MemberExpression' | new NewExpression'   

NewExpression' = MemberExpression Arguments MemberExpression' | NewExpression                           

CallExpression = MemberExpression Arguments CallExpression'

CallExpression' = ( Arguments | "[" Expression "]" | "." Identifier ) CallExpression' | e.

Arguments = "(" [ArgumentList] ")"

LeftHandSideExpression = NewExpression | CallExpression
```

So, the question is how to use left factoring for rule **LeftHandSideExpression** in my new grammar. I need it because intersection of First[LeftHandSideExpression] and First[CallExpression] is not empty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to avoid having decisions in the parsing where 2 productions and paths share a common token.
So basically you want to move terminals up to the front of productions if they are buried in other non terminals and shared.

You will basically want to factor out common tokens, and place them in new nonterminals to avoid non deterministic choices.

EG:
If I have this grammar:

```
S -> X | Y
X -> ab
Y -> ac
```

I'll have to "move" the terminal "a" up so that the parser doesn't get stuck when it tries to choose whether to take X or Y.

The solution is along the lines of:

```
S -> A'
A' -> a(X|Y)
X -> b
Y -> c
```

Be careful to consider all paths that could have bene taken before, including lambda (the empty string). Handling lambda is a special case, and will need further processing to get a decent grammar (or one that even reflects the language you want).

While yes, this adds extra nonterminals, it is an algorithm that does guarantee a deterministic grammar that doesn't need lookahead.

NOTE: Some language generators (that parse a grammar) can be specified with a lookahead value. Sometimes this is preferred for simplicity, but be aware that using more than a lookahead of 1, will GREATLY increase your lookahead table that will be included in your parser. It is on the order of N^k where n is the number of productions, and k is the lookahead.

This site explains it with the specific form that I used in my compilers class:
http://www.cs.sun.ac.za/rw711/2012term2/lectures/lec5/l5.pdf

If external site links aren't preferred, I can take some images of the slides and attach them here for future archiving.

I would recommend reading up on grammars, as they can be a lot of fun!

Comment: Hi, @1337GameDev! Thank you for reply. I know basics, but I can't make a left factorization for rule "LeftHandSideExpression", so I decided to ask how to do that.

Comment: @user44647 Please reply to the main post, as an answer, if you believe you have it solved.